# ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (15 bytes)

Tags: aes

Trying to encrypt data with a key.

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encrypt.py", line 12, in <module>
    cipher = AES.new('thisisabadkey', AES.MODE_ECB)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 95, in new
    return _create_cipher(sys.modules[__name__], key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py", line 79, in _create_cipher
    return modes[mode](factory, key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_ecb.py", line 215, in _create_ecb_cipher
    cipher_state = factory._create_base_cipher(kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 92, in _create_base_cipher
    expect_byte_string(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/_raw_api.py", line 175, in expect_byte_string
    raise ValueError("Incorrect AES key length (%d bytes)" % len(data))
```

To be able to encrypt data with the given key

Comment: AES keys need to be 16, 24 or 32 bytes for 128, 192, 256 bit key sizes. What's not clear? Do **not** confuse keys with passwords, use a method like PBKDF2 to derive a key if you *must* use a password.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for that. I eventually figured it out.